# Dividir filtros agrupados en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo esta informacion:
Lo que necesito es poder devolver total de property_type por barrios y que % ocupan del total de propiedades

[Df para testeo](https://pastebin.com/kHt4N3Jf)

Reducción de info:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
datos = pd.read_csv('dataset/datos_properati.csv', parse_dates= ['created_on'])
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
df_filtered = df[df.property_type != "store"]

df_filtered.property_type[df_filtered.property_type != 
'apartment'].groupby(df_filtered.barrio).value_counts()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
df_filtered.barrio.value_counts()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ej: En Belgrano tengo 1117 propiedades de las cuales 60 son house y 20 PH (El resto son apartment pero no me sirven para el caso por eso los filtro)
Necesito poder mostrar Que hay 60 apartment sobre 1117 propiedades y que representan el 5.37%.

¿Como podría hacer eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propongo esta respuesta que acabo de obtener, en caso de que tengan una mejor, subanla

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
datos = pd.read_csv('dataset/datos_properati.csv', parse_dates= ['created_on'])
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
df_filtered = df[df.property_type != "store"]

dfNuevo = 
pd.DataFrame(df_filtered.property_type.groupby(df_filtered.barrio).value_counts())

dfNuevo['Porcentaje'] = 
round((df_filtered.property_type.groupby(df_filtered.barrio).value_counts() * 100) / 
df_filtered.property_type.groupby(df_filtered.barrio).count(),2)

dfNuevo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]